# Why doesn't this regex work in grep?

Tags: regex, macos, grep

I have a file with these contents:

```
void verifyFooBar() {
}

void verifyFooBar123() {
}
```

I am using grep to match function names which start with `verify` but don't contain numbers using this command:
`grep verify[a-zA-Z]+\( *`

However I don't get any matches with grep. Why is this? I am able to see that this regex works using regex testers online. I am using OSX 10.9 if that matters.

Comment: Are you specifying the -E flag on your grep? This may be required for extended regex functionality.

Comment: I added the flag, now I get the error `grep: parentheses not balanced`. What does that mean?

Comment: `grep` doesn't handle the `+` as one would normally expect. Try using `grep verify[a-zA-Z]*.*\( *`

Comment: Single quote your regex string

Comment: @l'L'l that matches all function names. I only want to match function names without numbers. And how exactly does grep treat `+` differently?

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman I still get the same error after adding single or double quotes.

Comment: @Steven, grep treats it as a regular character unless it's escaped, so you could do `\\+` — `grep verify[a-zA-Z]\\+\( *`

Comment: @l'L'l that works now. Can you explain why two backslashes are needed to escape the `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quote your regex string (to prevent your shell grabbing any bits of it), do escape the plus, and don't escape your open paren (so it can be interpreted as a literal character).

```
grep 'verify[a-zA-Z]\+(' *
```

This is tested and works

Comment: I still get an error `grep: parentheses not balanced`. Perhaps it's because OSX has a different grep implementation?

Comment: I'm running this on OSX Yosemite. What grep version do you have?

Comment: Yes, the *older* apple version does differ. ((BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD).

Comment: `grep --version` shows `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. What version do you have?

Comment: I'm running that same version. To test, I just pasted your example names in a file `test` and ran `grep -e 'verify[a-zA-Z]\+( *' test`

Comment: Ok, this exact command `grep -e 'verify[a-zA-Z]\+(' *` works for me. Your answer had the `-E` capitalized which gave me the error.

Comment: You need uppercase `-E` for `egrep`, not lowercase.

Comment: @tripleee, see the comment immediately above yours. Extended regex is causing an issue, so using the regular regex flag was the fix.

Comment: grep DOES use basic regexps (BREs), you need to specify `-f` to tell it NOT so use regexps. `-e` is just to specify multiple regexps and avoid issues if the regexp begins with a `-` sign (otherwise it could look like an arg).

Comment: @EdMorton, you are right. -e is an unnecessary option, and the answer works without it. Answer edited.

Comment: That won't work with all greps, e.g. the default grep on Solaris.

Answer (score 3):

`+` is an ERE metacharacter. grep uses BREs by default. What you're trying to do written as a BRE would be:

```
$ grep 'verify[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*(' file             
void verifyFooBar() {
```

and if you want to use EREs you need to tell grep that with `-E` but then escape the `(` because that is also an ERE metacharacter but in this case you want it to be treated as a literal:

```
$ grep -E 'verify[a-zA-Z]+\(' file
void verifyFooBar() {
```

Some greps (and seds) have been enhanced in the past few years such that even when working on BREs you can "turn on" a given characters ERE metacharacter functionality by escaping it, e.g.:

```
$ grep 'verify[a-zA-Z]\+(' file 
void verifyFooBar() {
```

I think POSIX these days might even specify that you can use `\<ERE meta-char>` that way in BREs. The GNU tools do that, not sure which others. Some don't though, like the default tools on Solaris:

```
$ /bin/grep 'verify[a-zA-Z]\+(' file            
$
```

Comment: `+ is an ERE metacharacter`: Why does escaping it work? My posted answer works with the `\+` but not without.